# Hello, i am very new to coding in c, but i am getting an error message in c and i dont know why

Tags: c, syntax-error, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int number[];
    scanf("%d", &number);
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < number){
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error saying that an integer cant be compared with a pointer but im not sure how to fix it and dont understand why it doesnt work,.

```
type here
```

Comment: Your compiler lets you write `int number[];`?!?!  It should be giving you an error message for that.  What compiler are you using?  Because that's likely the root cause of your problems here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration of an array of incomplete type

```
int number[];
```

is invalid.

Just declare an object of the type `int` like

```
int number;
```

There is no any need to declare an array.

Instead of the while loop

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < number){
    printf("%d\n", counter);
    counter += 1;
}
```

it is better to use for loop like

```
for ( int counter = 0; counter < number; ++counter ){
    printf("%d\n", counter);
}
```

because the  variable `counter` is used only in the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

yes you declare as array number this declare as integer because array access as a pointer varible .
whole colde is

```
int number[];
```

replace with

```
int number;
```

whole code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < number){
        printf("%d\n", counter);
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```